# Understanding separate parts of passage from The Ferryman

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding, irish-english

I'm having trouble understanding of the separate parts of passage from The Ferryman (Jez Butterworth) What are the meanings of these sentences according to the passages: "spread-eagled round the back of the bingo"

Me and Diarmaid in the Shanty, we’re in the alley there, the Paras’ve got the nine-mill Browning in my ear. ‘I’m gonna scone you, you Irish fuck. Knock your fuckin’ cunt in.’ One of ’em sees I got the Republican News there sticking out my arse pocket. They’ve rolled it up and tried to shove it up my hole. Me and Finn Bailey, spread-eagled round the back of the bingo, this Para pulls the bolt of his
Sterling down. ‘Can you do an Irish jig?’ I’ll do no fucking Irish jig. I don’t even know one. They kicked us in the bollocks so hard Finn had an epileptic fit. His ma went to the police station. Waited seven hours. They made her fill out a form. ‘When did your boys get lifted and what happened?’ Then they whip out the lighter there and burn the fucking form and drop it in her lap.

Next part: What is the meaning of " brings out peat"?

SHANE. You a whiskey man? Here.
He pours him some in a cup.
Drop of water? Lots of men do, and there’s no shame to it. It brings out
the peat. Me, I like that punch in the back of the throat. That fire. You
want water?

and Final part: What's the meaning of "eat the bake off me"?

OISIN smashes the kite on the kitchen table, tearing it with his hands.
And runs out.
QUINN. Oisin!
CAITLIN. Let him go.
Silence.
MICHAEL. Well, that’s grand. Grand sense of humour on your man.
JJ. You was winding him up.
MICHAEL. Jesus Christ, it was just a bit of fun… We always have a bit of a
roar. It’s tradition.
JJ. You knew what you were doing.
MICHAEL. There’s no need to eat the bake off me. I was just having a laugh.
CAITLIN. Let him go. The boy’s had a head a steam up all summer. I’ll
speak to him later.

Answer (score 2):

(1) They were probably made to stand with arms and legs spread out (to be searched for weapons) in an alley at the back of a [bingo hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_(British_version))

(2) Some connoisseurs of whisky believe that adding a small amount of water improves the flavour. Good-quality Scotch whisky and Irish whiskey often has a peaty flavour from the local water used to make it.

(3) I don't know.

Comment: Can I make a guess? I think "eat the bake off" may be a metaphor for going beyond what is necessary. Maybe he feels he is being scolded too much. Eating the rice pudding is fair enough, but eating the baked on residue from the rim of the pudding bowl may be a bit more than is necessary. Hmmm!